# Node is installed during provisioning on vagrant but disappears upon connecting to ssh

Tags: 13.04, nodejs, vagrant

I am really getting sick of this and I don't know what is wrong. I am using **Vagrant 1.7.2** , **Ubuntu 13.04** , **Virtual Box 4.3 12 r93733**

My host machine is **Windows 8.1**

Here is my node bootstrap script found on my bootstrap.sh

```
echo "--- Installing Node.js ---"
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.16.1/install.sh | bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 0.12
nvm use 0.12
sudo cp ~/.nvm/versions/nodejs/v0.12/bin/node /bin/node

echo "--- Install node app dependencies --"
cd /var/www/html/node
npm install express
npm install youtube-audio-stream
```

During provisioning I could see that node is installed correctly . I could see the **Now using node v0.12** . I could also see that the **npm install**'s are successful

However when I connect using **vagrant ssh** . I get **No command 'nvm' found** . And **The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:** . I also checked **~/.nvm/** directory, it is not existing.

It becomes even weirder. So while I'm at ssh, I rerun the script again. Then nvm is now correctly installed and I could use node.

Comment: Is the script being run in normal user mode, sudo, or root?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found how to do it. And is very easy (way easier than I said).

In a nutshell, follow these steps:

1. Set Vagrantfile to run as normal user:

   ```
   config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh", privileged: false
   ```
2. Inside your provision file, do this:

   ```
   curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.24.1/install.sh | bash
   source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
   ```

The command above will, first, install nvm from github creationix, and refresh the shell to enable the provision to use nvm commands to install node and npm.

3. Then, you just do this:

   ```
   nvm install stable
   nvm alias default stable
   ```

The 'stable' will always be the latest stable version of node. So if you want a particular version, just change the 'stable' to the version you need.

The second line, where you type nvm alias, is just telling to nvm that it needs to use as default the version you passed to it. Then nvm will know which version of node to call when nvm run the commands of node and npm.

Credits to djheru for clarify things here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26691455

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken, vagrant provisioning runs as root.  NVM's install is specific to the user, and it adds commands to the current user's bash config (in this case, root).  Without those commands, NPM is not available in the shell.  You have to install NVM and node as the vagrant user, not root.

Also, you're using an old version of NVM.

```
sudo su vagrant -c 'curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.23.3/install.sh | bash'
sudo su vagrant -c '. ~vagrant/.nvm/nvm.sh;nvm install v0.12'
sudo su vagrant -c '. ~vagrant/.nvm/nvm.sh;nvm use v0.12'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I solved this. I haven't tried your answers yet so I can't accept any but this is what worked for me.

```
git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git /home/vagrant/.nvm && cd /home/vagrant/.nvm && git checkout `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`
source /home/vagrant/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 0.12
nvm use 0.12
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have to say that my answer is not a complete answer so read it carefully.

You need check out if your Vagrantfile is running provision as root. If so, you need to change to use like normal user:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh", privileged: false
```

The `privileged: false` will do this change for you.

Next, you will need to refresh the shell after the command to install nvm from github:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.24.1/install.sh | bash
source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

The `source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh` will do this for you. You can attach this command to your .bashrc file, in `$HOME/.bashrc` inside vagrant.

The sad thing is that you will need to export some environment variables of node and npm and put the command inside .bashrc too so when you enter via ssh in vagrant you will be able to use node and npm commands, but I don't know yet the right commands to do it, that's why I end up here hehehe...

Oh, and after add the commands to the .bashrc, you need to refresh the shell doing:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Well, now I just need to find how to export the variables when installing node with nvm to complete this task hehe...